# change image on click using 2 functions

Tags: javascript, image, function, click, event-listener

[Can someone see where Im goin wrong with this code?
using two functions to swap out an image](https://jsfiddle.net/dmchaledesigner/hps9v59o/)

```
    <button onclick="bulbOn();">Turn the lights On</button>
    <img id="myImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/8kGmXwB.png" alt="Light Bulb">
    <button onclick="bulbOff();">Turn the lights off</button>


   function bulbOn(){
   var el = document.getElementById('myImage');
   el.addEventListener('click', function(){
   this.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/2IRs7Bs.gif';
   });
```

}

```
    function.bulbOff(){
    var el = document.getElementById('myImage');
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/8kGmXwB.png';
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add event listener to document. Try this:

```
function bulbOn() {
    var el = document.getElementById('myImage');
    document.addEventListener('click', function() {
        el.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/2IRs7Bs.gif';
    });
}
function bulbOff() {
    var el = document.getElementById('myImage');
    document.addEventListener('click', function(){
        el.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/8kGmXwB.png';
    });
}
```

And, actually, there is no need of variable el. So:

```
function bulbOn() {
    document.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'http://i.imgur.com/2IRs7Bs.gif';
    });
}
function bulbOff() {
    document.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'http://i.imgur.com/8kGmXwB.png';
    });
}
```

Comment: @dmchale in this case, I suggest you to open the console and see what kind of errors you get. It tells `Uncaught ReferenceError: bulbOn is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`. Just change the LoadType in JS settings to "No wrap - in <head>" and it will get it to work :)